# copying or renaming an android project in eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

Iv'e tried to copy and paste a project in the same workspace. The project gets copied but doesn't run on my device.

If I leave the default name e.g "copy of myProject" it works.

If I try to rename using the refractor option the project shows an error:
"Android requires compiler compliance level 5.0 or 6.0. Found '1.7' instead. Please use Android Tools > Fix Project Properties.."
when I fix the project as suggested It fails load to my device

Comment: im not sure but try this go to the default.properties file of project and change the target .

Answer (score 1):

Go to project properties file and change the project name and clean and build the project.It should work then